# How to use buttons in jquery for form submission in php

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to submit the form in php from button in jquery I tried different ways by adding id for button, but I am unable to submit the values, as I am new to Jquery the task is a bit tougher can anyone suggest me how to solve it?

```
<form method="post" action="add_emp.php" class="form-horizontal form-label- 
 left">
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Employee Id </label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="empid" id="employee-id" required="required">
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name </label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
function SmartWizard(target, options) {
    this.buttons = { 
   finish : 
   $('<a>'+options.labelNext+'</a>').attr("href","#").addClass("buttonNext"),
    };
```

Comment: Are you trying to append button to the form or what exactly is your goal? From your post it is not clear what you want and also the JS code doesn't seem to be related to your HTML code.

Comment: I want to submit the form values into my database using the button which is in jquery. there is no code for button in html, but from jquery i am using finish button, i don't know how to perform action to the jquery button for submission. can you tell me how to use that jquery button for form submission in html or php page?

Comment: There is no way that the button doesn't have HTML when it is visible on the page. So I suppose the button is ADDED to the form with jQuery. But why is that? You can easily put the submit button to the HTML like shown in the answer below (`<input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="submit" />`) and then put some jQuery action on it like this: `$('#submit-btn).click(function(e) { <your code here> }`

Comment: without using html button i used to display button through jquery and it is displaying well. can't we do any operations by adding name or id for submitting?

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to submit the form you do not need jquery for this.

Just by adding `<input type="submit" value="submit"/>` at the bottom of the form should fix your problem.

your code will look like this:

```
<form method="post" action="add_emp.php" class="form-horizontal form-label- 
 left">
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Employee Id </label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="empid" id="employee-id" required="required">
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name </label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>
 </div>
 <input type="submit" value="submit"/> // added this line.
</form>
```